# some of my css fonts is not working while some are working

Tags: html, css, reactjs, fonts, font-face

here is my font face where i have my fonts and their directory respectively

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'Pacifico';
        font-style: normal;
        src: url('../fonts/Pacifico.ttf');
      }

  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Lobster';
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('../fonts/Aladin-Regular.ttf');
  }

  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Neo';
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('../fonts/Nunito-SemiBoldItalic.ttf');
  }

  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Lob';
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('../fonts/Lobster.otf');

  }
.nav{
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 5rem;
    font-family: 'Lobster';
}

.chat{
    font-family: 'Lob' !important;
  padding-right: 30rem;
}
.linkk{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Lobster';
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 6rem;
}
```

here is my home page where i have elements to style, the chat div, the linkk div, nav div and my form are not responding to font family i gave to them while some responded to the font i gave them, here is my code for the element below.

```
header>
            <Navbar bg="blue" expand= "sm">
                <Container fluid>
                    <div className="space"></div>
                    <div className="imagelogo">
                        <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="chat">
                        <Navbar.Brand>MyChat</Navbar.Brand>
                        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="nav">
                        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                            <Nav className="me-auto">
                                <div className="search">
                                    <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                                        <InputGroup.Text id="basic-addon1"></InputGroup.Text>
                                        <Form.Control
                                            placeholder="Search News"
                                            aria-label="Username"
                                            aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                                        />
                                    </InputGroup>
                                </div>
                                <Nav.Link href="/">HOME</Nav.Link>
                                <Nav.Link href="/">NEWS</Nav.Link>
                                <Nav.Link href="/">TIMELINE</Nav.Link>
                                <Nav.Link href="/">CONTACT</Nav.Link>
                            </Nav> 
                        </Navbar.Collapse>
                    </div>
                </Container>
            </Navbar>
        </header>

        <main>
            <Container>
                <Row className="px-4 my-5">
                    <Col sm={7}>
                    <div className="info">
                        <h2>Make Cool Friends !!!</h2>
                        <p>Friend Finder is a social network template that can be used to  <br />
                            connect people. The template offers Landing pages, <br />
                            News Feed, Image/Video Feed, Chat Box, Timeline and lot more. <br /><br />
                            What are you waiting for? <Link to ="">Join Now.</Link>
                        </p> 
                    </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={4}>
                        <div className="holdback">
                            <div className="linkk">
                                <Link to = "/" onClick={ActionLogin}>Login</Link> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <div className="line"></div> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <Link to = "/" onClick={ActionRegister}>Register</Link>
                            </div>
                                <form id="myLogin" className="login-form">
                                    <h1>Login</h1>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" /><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" /><br/><br/>
                                    <Button>Login</Button><br/><br/>
                                    <Link to = "/">Forgot Password?</Link>
                                </form>
                                <form id="myRegister" className="register-form">
                                    <h1>Register</h1>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" /><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" /><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="number" placeholder="Phone Number" /><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" /><br/><br/>
                                    <Button>Register</Button><br/><br/>
                                    Already have an account ?&nbsp;<Link to = "/" onClick={ActionLogin}>Login</Link>
                                </form>
                        </div>
```

Comment: try not to use ttf and otf, they're full system font. Instead use woff2, which is a compressed format for the web. But even without that change look at your dev tools: any network errors? console errors?

Answer (score 0):

Web Open Font Format (WOFF) developed in 2009 as a wrapper format for TrueType and OpenType is supported by all modern browsers! Try converting the font to this format and use it!

Or you can Use

```
<link href=' http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```